# Distinct Only 1 column

Tags: distinct-on

I am trying to write a query to return the sum of call time for each specific category. There are only 3 categories and i only want 3 rows to be returned with the sum of time. I thought using the distinct would work, but it also applies to the minutes too.

How can I manipulate this query to only be distinct on category?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    category, SUM(calltime)
FROM 
    table
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to use `GROUP BY` instead of distinct

```
SELECT SUM(calltime)
FROM table
GROUP BY catagory
```

Comment: if i am already grouping by date like this, do i just add the GROUP BY Catagory at the end also?

SELECT  catagory, SUM(calltime)
FROM table
GROUP BY DATEPART (wk, activity_date)
and catagory

Comment: @MidnightPolaris you can group by multiple columns or expressions like this `GROUP BY col1, col2, FN(col3)` which will multiply the rows returned